# Typescript type where an object consists of exactly a single property of a set of possible properties

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to model a particular pattern with the type system where an object consists of exactly a single property of a set of possible properties.

In other words, the type would be a partial type but with only one property allowed.

```js
interface PossibleProperties {
  cat?: AllPropsOfSameType;
  dog?: AllPropsOfSameType;
  cow?: AllPropsOfSameType;
}

interface ShouldBeExactlyOneOfPossibleProperties {
  [P in keyof PossibleProperties]: AllPropsOfSameType; // Wupz, this allows for 0 or more...
}
```

I've seen [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230773/how-to-create-a-partial-like-that-requires-a-single-property-to-be-set) for requiring at least one property:

```js
type AtLeastOne<T, U = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }> = Partial<T> & U[keyof U]
```

But I need something like `AtMostOne<T, U = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }>` or `ExactlyOne<T, U = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }>` which could possibly be the intersection type of `AtMostOne` and `AtLeastOne`

Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 9):

Using information throughout this whole post, I get the following as a solution:

```
type Explode<T> = keyof T extends infer K
  ? K extends unknown
  ? { [I in keyof T]: I extends K ? T[I] : never }
  : never
  : never;
type AtMostOne<T> = Explode<Partial<T>>;
type AtLeastOne<T, U = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }> = Partial<T> & U[keyof U]
type ExactlyOne<T> = AtMostOne<T> & AtLeastOne<T>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You are the goat, thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, but the credit is due to https://github.com/keithlayne as he came up with the solution on https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript

Credit is also due to https://github.com/fatcerberus who came up with the initial reasoning.

> I’m pretty sure there’s no way to model that in TS, simply because of how structural typing works. You can always have extra properties that the type doesn’t explicitly list
>
> Even if you make a union of single-property types, it’s no guarantee that you don’t have any of the others
>
> Hmm... I might be wrong. If you could make a type that maps over the keys and makes a union like `{a:string,b:never} | {a:never,b:string}` then that could work. Not sure how you’d do it though

Here goes Keith's answer:

```js
type Explode<T> = keyof T extends infer K
    ? K extends unknown
    ? { [I in keyof T]: I extends K ? T[I] : never }
    : never
    : never;
```

[in action](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJwBcyIArgLYBG0A3PodaQM5hSgDmDhyCp1TABsIcEAwC+uXGACeABxQBRAB7yh6ACYQAPABUAfMgC8yANYRZ6GMj3IIKyCE0tkoGNGQBpRgQD83vaOEM6u5CBmIOgA7iC+yAHYyADaAJJuIOaW1rYAuqTpDk4ugQF6abnIpCAQAG6eUrzVddDxzfVQDNJyirYQbCbIqupauhjoBgxAA)

This is probably easier to grok:

```js
type Split<T, K extends keyof T> = K extends unknown ? { [I in keyof T]: I extends K ? T[I] : never } : never;
type Explode<T> = Split<T, keyof T>;
```

Basically, map over `T` for each member of `keyof T`, and return the union.

Comment: I approve of this message.

Comment: on the [in action](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJwBcyIArgLYBG0A3PodaQM5hSgDmDhyCp1TABsIcEAwC+uXGACeABxQBRAB7yh6ACYQAPABUAfMgC8yANYRZ6GMj3IIKyCE0tkoGNGQBpRgQD83vaOEM6u5CBmIOgA7iC+yAHYyADaAJJuIOaW1rYAuqTpDk4ugQF6abnIpCAQAG6eUrzVddDxzfVQDNJyirYQbCbIqupauhjoBgxAA) site above, I tried `const test: Explode<Foo> = {a: 1};` and get an error "Type '{ a: number; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ a: number; b: never; c: never; }': b, c". What am I missing ? How do I successfully instantiate this type ?

Comment: I found the solution: The fields of Foo need to be set to optional. `interface Foo {a?: number; b?: string; c?: boolean;}`

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses types instead of an interface, but I think it does what you need.

First, define a base type which defines all the properties you want to support. They need to be *optional* and have a type of *never*:

```ts
type AnimalBaseType = {
  "cat"?: never;
  "dog"?: never;
  "cow"?: never;
}
```

Now, define a type for each animal, based on AnimalBaseType, but omit the corresponding "never" property and replace it with the property you want.

```ts
type CatType = Omit<AnimalBaseType, "cat"> & { "cat": string };
type DogType = Omit<AnimalBaseType, "dog"> & { "dog": string };
type CowType = Omit<AnimalBaseType, "cow"> & { "cow": string };
```

You now have three types, each of which only allows the one property. These can be combined into one type and exported to the rest of your project:

```ts
export type AnimalType = CatType | DogType | CowType;
```

And here are some tests you can try:

```ts
// A dog can *not* be a cat 
let dogCat : CatType = { dog: "woof" }

// A cat can *not* be a dog 
let catDog : DogType = { cat: "meow" }

// An animal *can* be a either cat, dog or cow
let cat : AnimalType = { cat: "meow" }
let dog : AnimalType = { dog: "woof" }
let cow : AnimalType = { cow: "moo" }

// You can *not* specify more than one animal
let zoo : AnimalType = { cat: "meow", dog: "woof", cow: "moo" }
```

You can see the result here: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=64&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAehAIGUBcEMCdrgO4EtoAty3AI1gM4Cm40AngA4nIaoDGWAJkQGaoB2RBpGJFA9gQKpcqADZ94-KolRcANHgCuSTETIByeCVhix4adFT92u8KAix2jAy1KUSAIk4A3IvEfByVcAEF2qAC2ugBChEQAKg7gALzgAN7A4OCOdLDQjgD8AFzgru4A3EkpjPwA5lm5%20fBFyan8yJV5RG41wAC%20wBbgAMLa6Tr2Piz88OBEsAzYAcFiijT0WPytyPDoXDwk3k7Vntu96VE%20cQDygegAPP5BoeFHRIqp6Y4AfOAAZAkpaRm5BNBrdhlcDtIr7AAi5XusXAZ0u11mYWI90epQqb0%208RK5UcfwBHGBoK80R6DWhp3O0CuM1uyIcjzoDVeHy%209UaeMBhKK3VJgVEnGwemmN30224HGg-AMAv2VhsRAAHgJEOB0MBFcrVNEEbpyQdoNCAD7gSFlI29MkOblgPzgNHgNLscAAKnY-Ggzrwgx%205gkSDRPXS4FygYN0TiWLRuUcyH4-BYjhBXRtvgdQcdLrdHq92Dt5V9RCQP1NwZNUPDXx%200cCRCZSe6-mFsxdjs9uEGRHQvDGP0U9tGDoawD9aaQuR1Yj1WKrKRrdc6I-t45pk4rkfK0dj8cTC8Lg%20QpYnU-31bjO%20TEAAmvwlGmna73Z6CFQ6KgWGRwIFRlsMFZpToV2HPcAC840PFdjxnRw50aPsNxSLcE0URlkFPfgdyAA)

Answer (score 1):

The first my thought was to create a union type, like:

```js
type ExactlyOne =
  { cat?: AllPropsOfSameType } |
  { dog?: AllPropsOfSameType } |
  { cow?: AllPropsOfSameType };
```

It's possible using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```js
type ExactlyOne<T, TKey = keyof T> = TKey extends keyof T ? { [key in TKey]: T[TKey] } : never;
type ShouldBeExactlyOneOfPossibleProperties = ExactlyOne<PossibleProperties>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=51&pln=7&pc=58#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOngCMA2EqU6ADtGMBJsgN4BQyyCcYA-AFzKZhSgDmAbkbIAJun6duvAcKYJ0Adyk8%20IIfQC%209emACe5ZAFEAHojD49AeRAQAPABUANMgcBpCHuQBeZAGtPdBhXAD4fVw8vCBNIEFEaAL0g12Q2OmQAbUTkUAjPAF0uBwz3AuRNZC5bADdoYX1DAGUAC3QAV3xRACEIU3NLGwgrGAxsPEJiMgoqGl8%20hAtrWztRnAIiEnIoSmoQ4SA)

But it still allows to assign an object with multiple properties:

```js
// this assignment gives no errors
const animal: ShouldBeExactlyOneOfPossibleProperties = {
  cat: 'a big cat',
  dog: 'a small dog'
};
```

It's because union types in TypeScript are inclusive and you cannot create an exclusive union type at the moment. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767176/4858777).

So we need to forbid additional properties somehow. An option might be to use `never` type, but unfortunately it's impossible to create an optional property of type `never` because `never | undefined` gives `undefined`. If it's ok to have `undefined` additional properties you can use the following monstrous type:

```js
type ExactlyOne<T, TKey = keyof T> = TKey extends keyof T
  ? { [key in Exclude<keyof T, TKey>]?: never } & { [key in TKey]: T[key] }
  : never;
```

And the resulted type looks like:

```js
({
    dog?: undefined;
    cow?: undefined;
} & {
    cat: string | undefined;
}) | ({
    cat?: undefined;
    cow?: undefined;
} & {
    dog: string | undefined;
}) | ({
    cat?: undefined;
    dog?: undefined;
} & {
    cow: string | undefined;
})
```

It's horrible... but It's close to what is expected.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOngCMA2EqU6ADtGMBJsgN4BQyyCcYA-AFzKZhSgDmAbkbIAJun6duvAcKYJ0Adyk8+IIfQC+9emACe5ZAFEAHojD49AeRAQAPABUANMgcBpCHuQBeZAGtPdBhXAD4fVw8vCBNIEFEaAL0g1xE2OmQAbUTkUGMTBHwAV1F7ROTnCM8QgF0pWwA3aGRNZAAydKzPHJBKvWquB06+5pEuBuhhegUQHmQ4EGAAWzh8LlNzSxt7DGw8QmIyCipMMN8GeVYuAHI4ZFxgfmZWK6cRcX5rwriIGFAIUSuWmEQA)

A disadvantage of this approach is an undescriptive error message if you try to assign an object with multiple properties, for example this assignment:

```js
const animal: ShouldBeExactlyOneOfPossibleProperties = {
  cat: 'a big cat',
  dog: 'a small dog'
};
```

gives the following error:

```js
Type '{ cat: string; dog: string; }' is not assignable to type '({ dog?: undefined; cow?: undefined; } & { cat: string | undefined; }) | ({ cat?: undefined; cow?: undefined; } & { dog: string | undefined; }) | ({ cat?: undefined; dog?: undefined; } & { cow: string | undefined; })'.
  Type '{ cat: string; dog: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ cat?: undefined; dog?: undefined; } & { cow: string | undefined; }'.
    Type '{ cat: string; dog: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ cat?: undefined; dog?: undefined; }'.
      Types of property 'cat' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)
```

---

Another approach: you can emulate an exclusive union type like suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767154/4858777). But in this case an extra property is added to the object.

```js
type ExactlyOne<T, TKey = keyof T> = TKey extends keyof T
  ? { [key in TKey]: T[TKey] } & { prop: TKey }
  : never;

const animal: ExactlyOne<PossibleProperties> = {
  prop: 'cat',
  cat: 'a big cat'
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=11&pln=7&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOngCMA2EqU6ADtGMBJsgN4BQyyCcYA-AFzKZhSgDmAbkbIAJun6duvAcKYJ0Adyk8+IIfQC+9emACe5ZAFEAHojD49AeRAQAPABUANMgcBpCHuQBeZAGtPdBhXAD4fVw8vCBNIEFEaAL0g1xE2OmQAbUTkUAjPAF0uBwz3AuRNZAAydNISUiLI8pEuWwA3aGF6BRAeZDgQYABbOHwuU3NLG3sMbDxCYjIKKkww3wYmWrIuAHIWMG2nET2duGRcYH5mVm2tYSA)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a possible solution:

```
interface PossibleProperties {
  cat?: any;
  dog?: any;
  cow?: any;
}

type keys = keyof PossibleProperties;

type Diff<S, T> = S extends T ? never : S;

type Container<T extends keys> = {
  [k in T]?:  never
}

type Single<R extends keys> = {
   [k in R]: PossibleProperties[k]
}

type All<R extends keys, T extends keys> = Single<R> & Container<T> 

type ExactOne<T> = T extends keys ? All<T, Diff<keys, T >> : never;

let d: ExactOne<keys> = {dog: 1}; //ok
let d2: ExactOne<keys> = {cat: 1}; //ok
let d3: ExactOne<keys> = {cow: 1}; //ok

let d4: ExactOne<keys> = {cow: 1, cat: 1}; //error
let d5: ExactOne<keys> = {}; //error
let d6: ExactOne<keys> = {huhu: true}; //error
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble getting @sebastian ferreira's answer to work, so I though I would post my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69388742/349169) here as well:

```
interface Foo {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
}

type AtMostOneOf<T> = keyof T extends infer K
    ? K extends unknown
    ? { [I in keyof T]+?: I extends K ? T[I] : never } // notice the '+?'
    : never
    : never;


type Test = AtMostOneOf<Foo>;

const test: Test = {a: 1}; // allowed
const test1: Test = {b: 'asd'}; // allowed
const test2: Test = {a: 1, b: 'asd'}; // not allowed
const test3: Test = {} // allowed
```

Comment: Empty object should not be allowed, you want exactly one property