# Primary key type from typescript interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Consider the following interface:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  address: {
    country: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    street: string;
  }
  active: boolean;
}
```

I need to create a generic PrimaryKey type, but it should correspond only to either string or number and omit any other type.

So in the case of `PrimaryKey<User>` only id, name, and email would be considered valid primary keys.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I recommend to read at following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158066/typescript-type-where-an-object-consists-of-exactly-a-single-property-of-a-set-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this one:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  address: {
    country: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    street: string;
  }
  active: boolean;
}

type ExtendedKeyOnly<T extends object, KeyType = string | number> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends KeyType ? K : never]: T[K];
};

type PrimaryKeyUser = ExtendedKeyOnly<User>;

type KeyOnlyPrimaryKeyUser = keyof PrimaryKeyUser;
```