# Typescript: validate that keys of Type objects are only one of K and single key:value pair

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror

I have the following code, which gives me `ts(1337)` error:

```js
type Options = 'option1' | 'option2' | 'option3'

type ComplexValue = { [key: Options]: string } // ts error 1337
```

what I want to achieve here is that keys of `ComplexValue` objects can be only one of `Options`.

if I try to fix and define it differently by one of the below options:

```js
type ComplexValue = { [K in Options]: string }

// or simply

type ComplexValue = Record<ServerFilterOperator, string>
```

and then trying to write something like this

```js
const something: ComplexValue = { option1: 'ziv' }
```

then I get the below error
`Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ComplexValue': option2, option3.ts(2740)`

A workaround I can apply is adding `?` to the definition `type ComplexValue = { [key in Options]?: string }` - this will apply that all keys are optional. But I actually wants to validate only single `key:value` are passed.

What is the proper way validate that keys of `ComplexValue` objects can be only one of `Options` and only one `key:value` pair is on the object?

[link to TS playground is here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA5E+yKAjDlAD676KoBMpFeBqAzDgFBuiRQDCSAtmAA2EAB4A1AIZCArtGwBvKAG0A1hBAAuWE3QBdbWmAAnBCgDmUAL4cAxqiNQ0AiMAAWZ89r6CRE6XJYUEpUhETaOABeCABupFZAA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript type where an object consists of exactly a single property of a set of possible properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158066/typescript-type-where-an-object-consists-of-exactly-a-single-property-of-a-set-o)

Comment: @TobiasS. checking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little tricky but you can get it done. Inspired by a few other answer I came up with this:

```
type RequireSingle<K extends PropertyKey> = {
  [P in K]: {[V in P]: string} & Partial<
    Record<Exclude<K, P>, never>
  > extends infer T
    ? {[X in keyof T]: T[X]}
    : never;
}[K];

type ComplexValue = RequireSingle<Options>;
const complex: ComplexValue = {};
// .  ~~~~~~~~ Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ComplexValue'.
const complex1: ComplexValue = {
  option1: ""
};
const complex2: ComplexValue = {
  //  ~~~~~~~~ Type '{ option1: string; option2: string; }' is not assignable
  //           to type 'ComplexValue'.
  option1: "",
  option2: ""
};
```

Comment: thanks @Behemoth - can you please elaborate and explain each of the operators. I'm relatively new with TS and I'm hard to understand how this magic works

Comment: I also have the following situation, where the key of `complex1` vairable is dynamically set. This prompts another TS error. see the playground in the next comment:

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA5E+yKAjDlAD676KoBMpFeBqAzDgFBuiRQBKEAjgFcEAJwgBlBCgDmAGwgAeANJQIAD2AQUAEwwAFEfggjQSiCAB8WKAG82UKAG09UKVCUBdAFy3HANVcUKD1vKDRgESlpAF8oADJggEMTBETZBXsHXggAYyQRbQUAUTUc2UFtRSUAGmCLWpQIADdjC0yrdU0dDCkAM2MoABVMhwB+XwANQKgAa3MkXqHQwccJj2iRqB9GlpEAbjZox08DznBoAGEkAFsweTU-NMFobD4hUQko+QU4anQLU55dDAKDXRJgABihmufiIwCQfhoPj4eQKChQgmuACNjLVfoQ0FZsHYslAiD5GH8SNVNkjKEwUHQaaTmBSqIRWDSNmwgeEwjcIMAABZRHxXW73R7lF62JxgyHQ2HwxGOIgeUI4ABeCCapGiQA